# Bayesian Decision Making (for particular problem)

Tags: bayesian, model-selection, posterior, likelihood-ratio, decision-theory

I've read several papers why p-values should be replaced by Bayes factors and trying to use them.

What I have: say, I have matrix of 2000 rows and 1000 columns. In each column I need to make a decision which model is more realistic: $M_0$: there are 2 classes in that column, $M_1$: there is only 1 class in that column. I have well defined point models for classes - say, 1 class can be modelled with $\xi_1 \sim \mathcal N(1, \sigma)$, 2nd class $\xi_2 \sim \mathcal N (2, \sigma)$. So it sounds like mixture modelling problem which may be solved by expectation-maximization and BIC.

Unfortunately, I have only "meta data" instead of raw points since $\xi_i$ are not actually normal, but complex models, and class one is a prevalent class (more than 99% of points belong to the 1st class). In the matrix most of the cells have 0 information: it means that "1st class is more probable". If there is something in the cell, it contains $-2LR = -2\log\frac{P(D|\xi_2)}{P(D|\xi_1)}$ - evidence in favour of 2nd class, and the doubled likelihood ratio is bigger than 40. Note: it is just a likelihood ratio (not a proper Bayes factor) since there is no integration.

My goal is: decide for each column whether one-class or two-class model is more probable, based on amount of evidences in favour to two-class model and strength of evidences. My goal is to keep FDR quite low (better lower than 3%). FDR can be checked as a separate procedure.

What I did now: if for particular column there is at least one evidence in favour to $\xi_2$ with $-2LR > 60$, I say that there are two classes.

**Question 1:** should I use posterior odds ratio instead of likelihood ratios as a score for making a decision? I have a prior knowledge about each column (number of "strong" evidences in favour to $\xi_2$) and have a prior knowledge about each row (some of rows are more noisy, normally we have $n$ evidences in favour to $\xi_2$, but some have $n+k$, so I can use $k$ as the number of potential false positives).

**Question 2:** for one column I need to make a decision if there is one class or 2 classes. Having $m$ evidences (likelihood ratios or posterior odds ratios) in favour to presence of $\xi_2$ (that may mean that there are 2 classes), how can I extract a summary statistic from them?

I am sorry for the long text. I will be perfectly OK with the empirical solution (like finding an empirical decision boundary that gives me good FDR) or any advice. I've read some related questions from stats.stackexchange, but was not able to solve my problem.